# How to solve this error: "internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638 throw err; ^"

Tags: node.js, json, vue.js, npm, webpack

I want to run my Vue.js using npm on localhost:8080 but they give me this error. Is there a way to solve this issue?

This error only occurs when I tried to install **node_modules** and **package-lock.json** in my Vue folder containing **.babelrc**, **package.json** and **webpack.config.js**. For my other Vue folders, I still can run my localhost:8080 by using the same method for all folders which is

> npm install
>
> npm run dev

The code below is the Error.

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\acer\Documents\VueJs\cross-env\dist\bin\cross-env.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-cli@ dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-cli@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-23T06_50_37_455Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 6):

Before you go uninstalling everything, try closing the terminal and trying again in a new Terminal instance

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue which I solved by noticing that when I followed the advice here: https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/1056#issuecomment-699456515
and proceeded to run `npm run build` which is what was giving me that error, it would work inside of the newly created project with `vue create <project-name>`.
I had my code in a repository so I recloned it, copied the node_modules folder into my working directory and then ran it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update NodeJS and it is not achieving, try the `nvm` instead.
I was trying in my Ubuntu and I used curl:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
```

If there isn't the file `.bashrc`, try execute: `source ~/.bashrc`

And then: `nvm list-remote`

Finally, install: `nvm install v13.6.0` (That's today version - 2021).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue; This issue is a result to your external hard-drive been corrupt or affected by virus. Format your external drive or better still create your application on your computer's drive instead of external drive.